# Resizing only way to repaint JFrame . repaint(); seems to not work

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, repaint

Im currently trying to make my first game and i am having trouble getting the repaint() method to work. I have checked my keyListeners and have confirmed that they are working a ok! The ship that i have created moves but only if i forcibly resize the window by dragging on the sides. If anyone has any tips i would be very greatful!

If you need any more information feel free to ask!

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import java.awt.event.KeyListener;




public class Main extends Canvas implements KeyListener{

public static Ship playerShip = new Ship(150,450,"F5S4-Recovered.png");

public int numberOfEnemies = 0;





public static void createFrame(){



   Window frame1 = new Window();

   final JPanel pane = new JPanel(){

     public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
        g.drawImage(playerShip.image, playerShip.xPos1, playerShip.yPos1, this);

    }     

  };

   frame1.add(pane);

}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){System.out.println("KeyTyped");}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){

    switch(e.getKeyCode())
    {
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT :
            playerShip.xPos1-=2;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            playerShip.xPos1+=2;
            break;


    }


    repaint();

}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){}

public static void main(String args[]){

     createFrame();

}
```

}

Window class ----------------------------------------------------------

```
    import javax.swing.*;



    public class Window extends JFrame{


        public Window()
        {
            setTitle("Space Game");
            setSize(800,800);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            addKeyListener(new Main());
            setVisible(true);

        }




    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `repaint()` is repainting the class `Canvas`, but the painting is done on the `JPanel pane`. The resizing causes an automatic repaint of the panel. So to fix you want to `pane.repaint()`, but you can't do that unless you put the panel as a class member, so you can access it from the listener method. Right now, it's currently locally scoped in the `createFrame()` method.

Also, you should probably add the listener to the panel instead, and not even extend `Canvas`, since you're not even using it

Other Notes:

- Look into using [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead of low-level KeyListener
- Swing apps should be run from the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). You can do so by simply wrapping the code in your `main` in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLate(..)`. See more at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)
- Again, I'll just add, Don't extends `Canvas`